# Fast sorting algorithm for integers

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have unsorted pairs of integers, which represent some time intervals (first number is always less than the second one). The problem is to assign an integer, so called channel number(0..x) to each time interval, so that the intervals which do not collide will share the same channel. The least possible number of channels should be used.

For example those intervals will use 2 channels:

50 100  //1

10 70   //0

80 200  //0

I've implemented it using counting sort, to sort the input by the first column, and then used linear search to find chains of pairs, which follow one another. I also first of all copy the input *const*array to the new one, and at the end, assign values to the correct positions in the input array.

Yes, it is an assignment I've got from the University, and its implemented already, but can anybody please tell me **how to make the code faster** ? **Which algorithm to use, so that sorting, chaining of pairs will be as fast as possible ?** The length of the input array is up to 10 millions elements.

Here is the code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;   

struct TPhone
 {
   unsigned int    m_TimeFrom;
   unsigned int    m_TimeTo;
   unsigned int    m_Channel;
 };

 class TElement
 {
 public:

  TPhone m_data;
  int index;

  TElement(TPhone  * const data, int index_)
  {
    m_data.m_TimeFrom=data->m_TimeFrom;
    m_data.m_TimeTo=data->m_TimeTo;
    m_data.m_Channel=-1;
    index=index_;
  }
  TElement()
  {
  }
 };

int FindNext(TElement** sorted_general_array, int general_array_size, int index_from)
{
  for (int i=index_from+1; i<general_array_size; i++ )
  {
    if (sorted_general_array[i]->m_data.m_TimeFrom > sorted_general_array[index_from]->m_data.m_TimeTo)
    {
      if (sorted_general_array[i]->m_data.m_Channel==(unsigned int)-1)
      {
        return i;
      }
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

int AssignChannels(TElement **sorted_general_array, int general_array_size)
{
  int current_channel=-1;
  for (int i=0; i<general_array_size; i++)
    {
      if (sorted_general_array[i]->m_data.m_Channel==(unsigned int)-1)
      {
        current_channel++;
        sorted_general_array[i]->m_data.m_Channel=current_channel;
        //cout << sorted_general_array[i]->m_data.m_TimeFrom << " " << sorted_general_array[i]->m_data.m_TimeTo << " " << sorted_general_array[i]->m_data.m_Channel << endl;
        int next_greater=i;
        while (1)
        {
          next_greater=FindNext(sorted_general_array,general_array_size,next_greater);
          if (next_greater!=-1)
          {
            sorted_general_array[next_greater]->m_data.m_Channel=current_channel;
            //cout << sorted_general_array[next_greater]->m_data.m_TimeFrom << " " << sorted_general_array[next_greater]->m_data.m_TimeTo << " " << sorted_general_array[next_greater]->m_data.m_Channel << endl;
          }
          else
          {
            break;
          } 
        }
      }
    }
    return current_channel;
}

int AllocChannels ( TPhone  * const * req, int reqNr )
 {
  //initialize
  int count_array_size=1700000;
  int * count_array;
  count_array=new int [count_array_size];
  for (int i=0; i<count_array_size; i++)
  {
     count_array[i]=0;
  }
  //
  int general_array_size=reqNr;
  TElement ** general_array;
  general_array=new TElement *[general_array_size];
  for (int i=0; i<general_array_size; i++)
  {
    general_array[i]= new TElement(req[i],i);
  }
  //--------------------------------------------------
  //counting sort
  //count number of each element
  for (int i=0; i<general_array_size; i++)
  {
    count_array[general_array[i]->m_data.m_TimeFrom]++;
  }
  //modify array to find postiions
  for (int i=0; i<count_array_size-1; i++)
  {
    count_array[i+1]=count_array[i+1]+count_array[i];
  }
  //make output array, and fill in the sorted data
  TElement ** sorted_general_array;
  sorted_general_array=new TElement *[general_array_size];

  for (int i=0; i <general_array_size; i++)
  {
    int insert_position=count_array[general_array[i]->m_data.m_TimeFrom]-1;
    sorted_general_array[insert_position]=new TElement;

    //cout << "inserting " << general_array[i]->m_data.m_TimeFrom << " to " << insert_position << endl;
    sorted_general_array[insert_position]->m_data.m_TimeFrom=general_array[i]->m_data.m_TimeFrom;
    sorted_general_array[insert_position]->m_data.m_TimeTo=general_array[i]->m_data.m_TimeTo;
    sorted_general_array[insert_position]->m_data.m_Channel=general_array[i]->m_data.m_Channel;
    sorted_general_array[insert_position]->index=general_array[i]->index;


    count_array[general_array[i]->m_data.m_TimeFrom]--;
    delete  general_array[i];
  }
  //free memory which is no longer needed
  delete [] general_array;
  delete [] count_array;
  //--------------------------------------------------

  int channels_number=AssignChannels(sorted_general_array,general_array_size);
  if (channels_number==-1)
  {
    channels_number=0;
  }
  else
  {
    channels_number++;
  }

  //output
  for (int i=0; i<general_array_size; i++)
  {
    req[sorted_general_array[i]->index]->m_Channel=sorted_general_array[i]->m_data.m_Channel;
  }


  //free memory and return
  for (int i=0; i<general_array_size; i++)
  {
    delete sorted_general_array[i];
  }
  delete [] sorted_general_array;

  return channels_number;
 }                                                             


int main ( int argc, char * argv [] )
 {
   TPhone ** ptr;
   int cnt, chnl;

   if ( ! (cin >> cnt) ) return 1;

   ptr = new TPhone * [ cnt ];
   for ( int i = 0; i < cnt; i ++ )
    {
      TPhone * n = new TPhone;
      if ( ! (cin >> n -> m_TimeFrom >> n -> m_TimeTo) ) return 1;
      ptr[i] = n;
    }

   chnl = AllocChannels ( ptr, cnt );

   cout << chnl << endl;
   for ( int i = 0; i < cnt; i ++ )
    {
      cout << ptr[i] -> m_Channel << endl;
      delete ptr[i];
    }
   delete [] ptr; 
   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: What's the max possible number range for those intervals? I suppose it's small because you used counting sort. The question is - how small is it?

Comment: The range is actually 0 to 1 million

Comment: Why do you think that the sorting itself is the bottleneck here? You can't do faster than counting sort when element values are quite small and 10 times less than maximum array size.

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem is with the sorting or not. If it's possible to do some better sorting I will work on it, if not then I will look through the rest of the code. Do you think that I should try a different sort or not ?

Comment: I though about it. Here I have search n * n times for the elements. Any idea how to improve it ?

Comment: oops where is my comment...
sorry, i won't come with an idea about it at the moment (because i didn't try to understand your solving method), but i think that your sorting algorithm is fine. Btw, are you sure that greedy method would work here?..

Comment: There is no memory limit, the run time is the issue. If the sorting is OK, then the algorithm for finding the sets of pairs is to slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your algorithm to be fast, you should reduce searching as much as possible. Also, you do not need to know which intervals are "chained together" for determining a correct channel for each (i. e. not using more channels than absolutely necessary). Here are the steps/techniques I would use for maximum performance:

1. Define your interval class like this, adding the two inline function definitions (that I use a struct for the TimeDescriptor is simply a matter of style, not that this code is exactly stylish, though):

   ```
   typedef struct TimeDescriptor {
       unsigned time;
       bool isEnd;
   } TimeDescriptor;

   class TimeInterval {
       public:
           TimeDescriptor start, end;
           unsigned channel;

           TimeInterval(unsigned startTime, unsigned endTime) {
               start = (TimeDescriptor){ startTime, false };
               end = (TimeDescriptor){ endTime, true };
           }
   }

   inline TimeInterval* getInterval(TimeDescriptor* me) {
       return (me->isEnd) ? (TimeInterval*)(me - 1) : (TimeInterval*)me;
   }

   inline TimeDescriptor* getOther(TimeDescriptor* me) {
       return (me->isEnd) ? (me - 1) : (me + 1);
   }
   ```
2. Create an array of pointers to all TimeDescriptors, two for each TimeInterval (one for the start, the other for the end).
3. Sort this array of TimeDescriptor pointers by the time. Make sure that you use the `isEnd` flag as a secondary sort key. I'm not sure how interval collisions are defined, i. e. whether the two intervals (20, 30) and (30, 40) clash or not, if they clash, sort end times after start times with the same value, if they do not clash, sort end times before start times with the same value.

   In any case, I would advise to just use a standard quicksort implementation to sort your array.
4. Create a stack for unused channel numbers. The important things about this stack are: It must allow you to fetch/push a channel number in constant time, ideally by updating no more than two numbers in memory; and it must be bottomless, i. e. it must allow you to pop any number of values, producing an ascending sequence of integers.

   The easiest way to implement such a stack, is probably to program a small class that uses an `std::vector<unsigned>` to store the free channels, and that keeps track of the largest channel number ever used. Whenever a pop request cannot be serviced from the internal storage, a new channel number is produced by incrementing the largest channel number by one.
5. Walk through your sorted array of TimeDescriptors. Every time you encounter a start time, fetch a channel number, and store it in the corresponding TimeInterval (using `getInterval()`). Every time you encounter an end time, push its channel number back onto the free channel array.
6. When you are through, your free channel stack will tell you the maximum number of channels you used simultaneously, and every TimeInterval will contain the correct channel number to use. You can even efficiently compute all the interval chains that share a channel by simply resorting the TimeInterval array by the channel number...

Answer (score 4):

This question already has an accepted answer.  However I wanted to describe a slightly different approach than the accepted answer.

**You've Got To Measure**

You aren't going to be able to tell anything about performance without measuring.  And to measure we need test cases.  So it seems to me that the first job is to create a program that will generate test cases.

I made a whole bunch of assumptions, which may be incorrect, and generated the following code to generate test cases:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int
main()
{
    const unsigned N = 10000000;
    std::mt19937_64 eng(0);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> start_time(0, N);
    std::chi_squared_distribution<> duration(4);
    std::cout << N << '\n';
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < N;)
    {
        unsigned st = start_time(eng);
        unsigned et = st + static_cast<unsigned>(duration(eng));
        if (et > st)
        {
            std::cout << st << ' ' << et << '\n';
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```

One can vary the value of `N`, the range of the seeding on the random number engine (if not the choice of random number engine), the range of start times, and the type/shape of the probability distribution of time durations.  I pulled each of these choices out of thin air.  Your professor may have better ideas on the generation of reasonable test cases for this problem.  But measuring **something** is better than measuring nothing.

**Make use of the `std::lib`**

The standard library is full of containers and algorithms.  Not only is this code debugged, it is efficient.  Re-use of this code is good coding style because:

1. It teaches you to recognize containers, and when to use what container.
2. It teaches you to recognize algorithms, and when to use what algorithm.
3. It can help you identify the need for, and code your own containers and algorithms when they are not supplied by the `std:lib`.
4. It makes your code much easier to read for others, because they will know about std-defined containers and algorithms.
5. It makes your code much easier to debug, because the probability of bugs in your code is much higher than the probability of bugs in the `std::lib` (though neither probability is zero).

**For Example**

I augmented your `TPhone` struct with I/O to ease the complexity of the I/O you are doing in main:

```
friend
std::istream&
operator>>(std::istream& is, TPhone& p)
{
    return is >> p.m_TimeFrom >> p.m_TimeTo;
}

friend
std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const TPhone& p)
{
    return os << '{' <<  p.m_TimeFrom << ", "
                     <<  p.m_TimeTo << ", "
                     << p.m_Channel << '}';
}
```

And I chose `vector<TPhone>` to hold all the calls.  This simplifies this:

```
int main ( int argc, char * argv [] )
 {
   TPhone ** ptr;
   int cnt, chnl;

   if ( ! (cin >> cnt) ) return 1;

   ptr = new TPhone * [ cnt ];
   for ( int i = 0; i < cnt; i ++ )
    {
      TPhone * n = new TPhone;
      if ( ! (cin >> n -> m_TimeFrom >> n -> m_TimeTo) ) return 1;
      ptr[i] = n;
    }
```

Down to this:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    vector<TPhone> ptr;
    int cnt;
    if (!(cin >> cnt)) return 1;
    ptr.reserve(cnt);
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
    {
        TPhone n;
        if (!(cin >> n)) return 1;
        ptr.push_back(n);
    }
```

And as it turns out my version is more efficient than yours.  I get this efficiency "for free", just by learning how to use `std::vector`.

`AllocChannels` can now take a `std::vector<TPhone>&`:

```
int
AllocChannels(std::vector<TPhone>& ptr)
```

In here I used the simplest possible algorithm I could think of.  Not because I thought it might be fastest, but because you need a baseline to measure against.  And as it turns out, simple is not always slow…

```
int
AllocChannels(std::vector<TPhone>& ptr)
{
    using namespace std;
    if (ptr.size() == 0)
        return 0;
    // sort TPhone's by x.m_TimeFrom
    sort(ptr.begin(), ptr.end(), [](const TPhone& x, const TPhone& y)
                                       {
                                           return x.m_TimeFrom < y.m_TimeFrom;
                                       });
   // Create channel 0 and mark it as busy by the ptr[0] until ptr[0].m_TimeTo
    vector<unsigned> channels(1, ptr.front().m_TimeTo);
    ptr.front().m_Channel = 0;
   // For each call after the first one ...
    for (auto i = next(ptr.begin()); i != ptr.end(); ++i)
    {
        // Find the first channel that isn't busy at this m_TimeFrom
        auto j = find_if(channels.begin(), channels.end(),
                                           [&](unsigned tf)
                                             {
                                                 return tf < i->m_TimeFrom;
                                             });
        if (j != channels.end())
        {
           // Found a non-busy channel, record it in use for this call
           i->m_Channel = j - channels.begin();
           // Mark the channel busy until m_TimeTo
           *j = i->m_TimeTo;
        }
        else
        {
            // Record a new channel for this call
            i->m_Channel = channels.size();
            // Create a new channel and mark it busy until m_TimeTo
            channels.push_back(i->m_TimeTo);
        }
    }
    return channels.size();
}
```

I've used a few C++11 features because they are convenient (such as auto and lambdas).  If you do not have these features available to you, they are easy to work around in C++03.  The basic algorithm I've used is to just sort by `m_TimeFrom`, and then do a linear walk through the sorted list of calls, and for each call a linear search through the set of channels looking for one that is not in use (creating a new one if all are in use).  Note the use of the standard algorithms `sort` and `find_if`.  No sense in re-implementing these, especially for a base-line test case.

I used `<chrono>` to time everything:

```
auto t0 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
int chnl = AllocChannels(ptr);
auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
```

I instrumented your code in exactly the same way so that I could test both.  Here are my results, first generating a test case of length = {100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000}, and for each length running first your code then mine, both using this output only:

```
cout << "#intervals = " << cnt << '\n';
cout << "#channels = " << chnl << '\n';
cout << "time = " << chrono::duration<double>(t1-t0).count() << "s\n";
```

Here is what I got:

```
$ clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -O3
$ a.out > test.dat
$ clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -O3
$ a.out < test.dat
#intervals = 100
#channels = 10
time = 0.00565518s
$ clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -O3
$ a.out < test.dat
#intervals = 100
#channels = 10
time = 6.934e-06s

$ clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -O3
$ a.out > test.dat
$ clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -O3
$ a.out < test.dat
#intervals = 1000
#channels = 17
time = 0.00578557s
$ clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -O3
$ a.out < test.dat
#intervals = 1000
#channels = 17
time = 5.4779e-05s

$ clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -O3
$ a.out > test.dat
$ clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -O3
$ a.out < test.dat
#intervals = 10000
#channels = 16
time = 0.00801314s
$ clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -O3
$ a.out < test.dat
#intervals = 10000
#channels = 16
time = 0.000656864s

$ clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -O3
$ a.out > test.dat
$ clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -O3
$ a.out < test.dat
#intervals = 100000
#channels = 18
time = 0.0418109s
$ clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -O3
$ a.out < test.dat
#intervals = 100000
#channels = 18
time = 0.00788054s

$ clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -O3
$ a.out > test.dat
$ clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -O3
$ a.out < test.dat
#intervals = 1000000
#channels = 19
time = 0.688571s
$ clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -O3
$ a.out < test.dat
#intervals = 1000000
#channels = 19
time = 0.093764s

$ clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -O3
$ a.out > test.dat
$ clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -O3
$ a.out < test.dat
Segmentation fault: 11
$ clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -O3
$ a.out < test.dat
#intervals = 10000000
#channels = 21
time = 1.07429s
```

**Summary**

No one here, including myself, predicted that the most simplistic solution would consistently beat your first try by whopping amounts.  This could be a characteristic of the test cases I've generated.  That would be something else for you to study by generating other test cases to measure against.

I do not know the cause of the Segmentation fault for your case with N = 10000000.  I did not take the time to study your code.  Quite frankly, I find your code complicated.

I neglected to write a correctness test.  That should actually have been my first step.  Is the output correct?  I got lazy and simply glanced at the N == 100 case to see if it looked right.

Because of the re-use of std::containers and algorithms, my code will actually be much easier to tweak for performance than yours.  For example you could try `std::lower_bound` (a binary search) in place of `std::find_if`, and *measure* if it improves things or not (I'm betting not, but you should measure, and with a `test.dat` that you have respect for).

Factor your code into containers and algorithms.  Reuse std-defined containers and algorithms when they exist, else create ones of your own that can be reused in your future coding.  As a student, I expect the std-defined ones to be adequate for most of your use cases.

Always test for correctness (as I failed to do so here :-)) Don't assume anything about performance without measuring.  Binary searching is not always faster than linear searching, even though it has a better asymptotic complexity.  And the input data can strongly impact the performance of your algorithms.  Learn how to generate varied input data to get a feel for how your algorithms can be impacted.  `<random>` is great for this task.

Answer (score 2):

Store the entries in a `std::vector<TPhone>` instead of in a `TPhone **`. This will layout consecutive `TPhone` objects consecutively in memory, leading to fewer cache misses.

Experiment with other data types than `unsigned int` for the members of `TPhone`. See [`<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) for types that you can try.

Answer (score 0):

Let [a<sub>i</sub>, b<sub>i</sub>) be your intervals, i = 1, ..., n.  You want to design a function channel(i) that returns a channel number for each of your n intervals.

The only constraint you have is that no two intersecting intervals can be on the same channel.  This corresponds to an undirected graph where your  intervals are vertices and there is an edge between two vertices if and only if the corresponding intervals intersect.

You can assign a channel C to a particular set of vertices (intervals) if those vertices form an [independent set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_%28graph_theory%29).

You want to find a set of independent sets of this form, where the union of all of them covers the graph, and they are pairwise disjoint.  You want as few independent sets as possible.

The (related) problem of finding a maximum independent set is NP-complete.  So I don't think you should expect to find a polynomial-time algorithm for finding the solution that gives you the minimum number of channels.

More realistic expectations come in one of two forms: either (A) spend super-polynomial time to solve the problem, or (B) use an approximation algorithm that may not give you a global optimum.

For (B) you can do this:

```
feasible(M)

    initialize M empty channels (lists of intervals)

    sort intervals by a_i value

    for each interval I = [a_i, b_i):

        insert it into the channel for which the most recent
        interval is closest to the current interval (but not intersecting)

        if I cannot be inserted at the end of any channel, return false

    return true //the M channels are a feasible solution
```

Now using this procedure you can exponential search for the minimum M for which feasible returns true.

Try M = 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ... until you hit the first M = 2<sup>k</sup> such that `feasible(M)` returns true.  Then do binary search between 2<sup>k - 1</sup> and 2<sup>k</sup> to find the minimum M.

Comment: Can you advice me some algorithm for B ? (an approximation algorithm that may not give you a global optimum.) I have a lot of memory, but time is very limited.

Comment: @John Updated the answer with an algorithm for (B).

Comment: I disagree on your assertion about the complexity of the problem. It may be correct that finding a maximum independent set is NP-complete in the general case, but the problem is a special case in which a very efficient algorithm exists. For details, see my answer, it's of complexity O(n log n).

Comment: @cmaster Without a proof that your answer finds the *optimal* solution, I'm not immediately convinced.  However it looks like you spent more time thinking about it so you're probably right.

Comment: @cmaster After a second look at your solution, I think you're actually not right. I don't see any reason why that algorithm will always get you the optimal number of channels. It's a greedy algorithm.

Comment: @TimothyShields It will never use more channels than there are concurrent time intervals, because it will first reuse all channels that have at least been used once before opening a new one. It is clear that you cannot reduce the amount of used channels further. It is true that it works in a greedy way, but that's for speed only, it does not have any influence on the maximum number of channels used.

Comment: @cmaster That's not a proof.  That's a sound argument for your particular greedy approach.  I believe certain NP-complete packing algorithms also reduce to this problem.  Think carefully about how solid your reasoning is when the number of channels needed becomes very large.  Are you sure a large gap in a channel early on won't allow for a tighter packing later in the channel?  You're making a false claim when you say your algorithm is optimal.  Not trying to attack you, because it's a fine approximation algorithm, but it's not exact.

Comment: @TimothyShields Well, my reasoning is excrutiatingly simple: You cannot use less channels than there are concurrent phone calls. No correct solution can hope to overcome this limit. Since the algorithm in my answer reaches this limit, it must be optimal in that respect. This is the entire proof. Note: I can easily imagine variations of the problem that would make it hard, like each phone call requesting a different number of _consecutive_ channels. My algorithm would not be adaptable to such a situation without becoming suboptimal. But the question is not about such a hard variation, luckily.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the collection sorted, why would you use a linear search? Use a binary search.

Comment: You are right, I will try that. Is it possible to use something faster than binary search here ?

Comment: I don't know the problem domain. Can you use a hash map? If your data set is large you will already get an enormous improvement from binary search.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being a necromancer here, but after reading the question and posted answers, I just could not let this one go.

### Channel Assignment Algorithm:

The problem has a greedy solution which is extremely efficient. Consider the following recursion:

- Assign first interval to channel 1
- For each remaining interval:

  - For each channel (assigned at least 1 interval):

    - If no conflicts exist with assigned intervals, assign interval to this channel and process next interval.
  - If conflicts existed in all channels, assign interval to a new channel.

This will produce the optimum number of channels. Proof is trivial, by induction on number of intervals.

### Sorting the Inputs

The key to speed lies in "if no conflicts exist". This means there will be comparisons between what has been processed and what is left to process, and it should be easy enough to convince yourself that sorting the inputs first is going to be faster in the end than sorting them as they are processed (or not sorting them at all).

If you aren't convinced, consider the following two extremes:

1. All intervals overlap.
2. No intervals overlap.

#### Choosing a Sorting Algorithm

We need to sort the inputs by start, then end time. This is easy enough if we choose a stable sort, and sort first by end time, then by start time. A stable version of Counting Sort is likely the best option given that all the values are integers; the number of inputs is much greater than the range of inputs; and memory usage is not an important consideration. This sort is linear in the number of inputs under these conditions.

### Sorting the Channels

By sorting the inputs, we need only compare each interval to the last interval assigned to each channel. In the extreme case where no intervals overlap, this algorithm is then linear: O(n) sort, + O(n) processing = O(n). On the other end of the extreme where all intervals overlap, without further improvements the algorithm would be quadratic.

To improve this, rather than compare against all channels, if the channels were sorted by earliest end time, then a conflict with the first channel would automatically indicate that all channels conflict. Then for each interval we need only 1 comparison, and whatever is required to maintain the sorted order of the channels.

For this, I would propose keeping the channels in a min-heap (by end time). The channel needed for the comparison would always be at the top. Peek at that channel, and:

- If there is an overlap, create a new channel, adding that to the heap. This new channel may have to move up the heap at a cost of O(lg m) where m is the current number of channels.
- Otherwise, pop the min channel O(lg m), add the interval to it (changing it's value) and add it back to the heap normally O(lg m).

In the worst-case nightmare scenario, the sorted intervals would have monotonically increasing start times, and monotonically decreasing end times. This give us the worst-case for the algorithm of O(n + lg 1 + lg 2 + ... + lg n) = O(n + lg(n!)) = O(n + n lg n) = O(n lg n)

### Real-World

Asymptotically better is not always better. It really depends on the distribution of inputs, as well as the size of the inputs. I'm confident the algorithm described here is superior to the others presented, but there is certainly room in the implementation for choices which are asymptotically identical, but will produce different results.